# Set a system property before log4j initialization

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, log4j

i need my log files inside `/web-inf/logs` folder, so i am trying to give the relative path to log4j

i am trying this code in a listener :

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    ServletContext context = event.getServletContext();
    System.setProperty("azraspinaRootPath", context.getRealPath("/"));

}
```

and this code in log4j.xml file

```
<rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <param name="FileNamePattern" value="${azraspinaRootPath}WEB-INF/logs23/hibernate-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz" />
</rollingPolicy>
```

and this line of code in web.xml :

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>ir.raysis.azraspina.startup.servlet.StartupListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

but it seems that log4j initialize before this listener, because it stores my log files in `home/web-inf/logs`

what can i do to make this work? this may be a bad practice so if you know better practice to do this in a shared tomcat, let me know. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

In web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="log4j-webapp-demo" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Log4JTestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Log4JTestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Log4JInitServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.Log4JInitServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>log4j-properties-location</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Log4JTestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In class,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger; 

import java.io.*; 
import java.sql.SQLException; 
import java.util.*; 

public class log4jExample{ 



 /* Get actual class name to be printed on */ 
 static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( 
 log4jExample.class.getName());  

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 throws IOException,SQLException{ 

 log.debug("Hello this is an debug message"); 
 log.info("Hello this is an info message"); 
 } 
}
```